# Is Plug and Play ID (PNPID) Unique For Each Device?

Tags: windows

I Use Windows and want find a Unique ID For External HDD Connected Via USB
I Find that's PnpID  = 0010101D400000000
is this Unique? if I Connect that to other windows and PC's that's not change?
and any other HDD can't have this PnpID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNPID is unque, as it is a combination of VendorId and deviceID. Every device will have its own unique PNPID.